# angular.js $resources setting Authorization header

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, preflight

js

what I'm trying to do is making REST API REQUEST to server.

A request should be 'GET' method and include 'Authorization' header.

my factory code which communicate REST server is like this
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('mabidualApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource, config) {

    return $resource(config.API+':url/:id', {
        url: '@url', id: '@id'
    }, { //parameters default
      auth: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            url: "token",
        }
    },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer oLDMYrJD0Qg15Nhv7N-H6w'} ,
        params: {
          url:"users",
          id:'me'
        }
      }
});
```

the fitst problem is here

```
headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer oLDMYrJD0Qg15Nhv7N-H6w'} ,
```

If I add header the method changes to 'OPTIONS' not 'GET'. I found out it's about CORS preflight something, but I couldn't figure it out how to disable it..

so I tried to change my configuration in app.js

```
  .config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Authorization'] ='Bearer oLDMYrJD0Qg15Nhv7N-H6w';
```

the second problem is here

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Authorization'] ='Bearer oLDMYrJD0Qg15Nhv7N-H6w';
```

It makes the error below.

```
Cannot set property 'Authorization' of undefined
```

Is there any solution to send A 'GET' request with 'Authorization' header?
thanks

Comment: Here is a good answer on another question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771062/how-to-pass-headers-on-the-fly-to-resource-for-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using params in the wrong way in your get request. Try switching params and headers like that  :

```
angular.module('mabidualApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource, config) {

    return $resource(config.API+':url/:id', {
        url: '@url', id: '@id'
    }, { //parameters default
      auth: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            url: "token",
        }
    },
      get_auth: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          url:"users",
          id:'me'
        },
        headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer oLDMYrJD0Qg15Nhv7N-H6w'}
      }
});
```

I changed your custom get request because 'get' might be defined by angular already, but I'm not sure :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get_auth['Authorization'] ='Bearer oLDMYrJD0Qg15Nhv7N-H6w';
```

Besides, are you sure you don't need any other headers?

Comment: Thanks but switching params and header brings the same result. and I want to set 'GET' header not custom request header..