# How to pass headers on the fly to $resource for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Right now, the only way that I know for setting tokens in headers dynamically for an angularjs call is via `$http` like so:

```
return $http.get({
  url: 'https://my.backend.com/api/jokes',
  params: {
    'jokeId': '5',
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ $scope.myOAuthToken
  }
});
```

But I want to figure out how to pass this via $resource, here's some pseudo-code that doesn't work:

```
...
.factory('myFactory',
  ['$resource',
    function($resource){
      return {
        jokes: $resource('https://my.backend.com/api/jokes', null, {
          query: {
            method: 'GET'
          }
        })
      };
    }
  ]
);
...
return myFactory.jokes.query({
  'jokeId': '5',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ $scope.myOAuthToken
  }
});
```

How can I  pass headers on the fly to $resource for angularjs?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't think this can be done the way you are trying, as the config object is not available on action method. But the action config method has it. So what you can do is, rather than returning resource directly, create a function that takes a parameter the authorization token and then construct the resource and return.

```
return {
    jokes: function (token) {
        return $resource('https://my.backend.com/api/jokes', null, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Then call the service function as:

```
myFactory.jokes($scope.myOAuthToken).query({'jokeId': '5'});
```

Comment: I tried it out, worked like a charm! Thanks @Chanermani! 
Sample Code: 
    `sample.factory('Restricted', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return {
        createRestrictedResource: function(token) {
            return $resource('/api/v1/restricted', null, {query: {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}}});
        }
    }
}]);`